# BadArgumentError: _MultiQuery with cursors requires __key__ order in ndb

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I can't understand what this error means and apparently, no one ever got the same error on the internet

> BadArgumentError: _MultiQuery with cursors requires `__key__` order

This happens here:

```
return SocialNotification.query().order(-SocialNotification.date).filter(SocialNotification.source_key.IN(nodes_list)).fetch_page(10)
```

The property `source_key` is obviously a key and `nodes_list` is a list of entity keys previously retrieved.

What I need is to find all the `SocialNotifications` that have a field `source_key` that match one of the keys in the list.

Comment: All i have found for this is comment in SDK source code above the statement raising this execption: "Cursors are supported for certain orders only". I guess: if you are using cursors, you have to set up order by key for some reason, but it doesnt make much sense to me..

Comment: I am doing almost this exact query. Did you find a way to solve the problem, or re-design the data to work around it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message tries to tell you you that queries involving IN and cursors must be ordered by `__key__` (which is the internal name for the key of the entity).  (This is needed so that the results can be properly merged and made unique.)  In this case you have to replace your `.order()` call with `.order(SocialNotification._key)`.

Comment: I know you're no more working on app engine team. But is it a good practice to use a private key in such manner? If yes, then why not making it public?

Comment: __key__ is the name in the Datastore, not in Python. It has the special form to avoid collisions with user-defined properties.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this also happens when you filter for an inequality and try to fetch a page.
(e.g.  `MyModel.query(MyModel.prop != 'value').fetch_page(...)` . This basically means (unless i missed something) that you can't fetch_page when using an inequality filter because on one hand you need the sort to be `MyModel.prop` but on the other hand you need it to be `MyModel._key`, which is hard :)

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors

You can change your query to:

`SocialNotification.query().order(-SocialNotification.date, SocialNotification.key).filter(SocialNotification.source_key.IN(nodes_list)).fetch_page(10)`

in order to get this to work. Note that it seems to be slow (18 seconds) when nodes_list is large (1000 entities), at least on the Development server. I don't have a large amount of test 
data on a test server.

Answer (score 2):

You need the property you want to order on and key.

```
.order(-SocialNotification.date, SocialNotification.key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when filtering without a group.
The error occurred every time my filter returned more than one result.

To fix it I actually had to **add** ordering by key.