# EndpointsAliasProperty filtering error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am trying to implement custom query responses using EndpointsAliasProperty. Here is the code

```
self._endpoints_query_info._filters.add(MyModel.hash_tag.IN(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

It is giving me an error

```
BadArgumentError: _MultiQuery with cursors requires __key__ order
```

how can I solve this? Is there a way to implement above idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question about the general problem here:
[BadArgumentError: _MultiQuery with cursors requires __key__ order in ndb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449197/)

To accomplish the necessary ordering with endpoints the easiest way is to explicitely add it to your query method:

```
@MyModel.query_method(...)
def mymodel_list(self, query):

    ...
    query = query.order(MyModel._key)
    return query
```