# GAE NDB Sorting a multiquery with cursors

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-ndb

In my GAE app I'm doing a query which has to be ordered by date. The query has to containt an IN filter, but this is resulting in the following error:

```
BadArgumentError: _MultiQuery with cursors requires __key__ order
```

Now I've read through other SO question ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449197/badargumenterror-multiquery-with-cursors-requires-key-order-in-ndb)), which suggest to change to sorting by key (as the error also points out). The problem is however that the query then becomes useless for its purpose. It needs to be sorted by date. What would be suggested ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloud Datastore server doesn't support `IN`. The NDB client library effectively fakes this functionality by splitting a query with `IN` into multiple single queries with equality operators. It then merges the results on the client side.

Since the same entity could be returned in 1 or more of these single queries, merging these values becomes computationally silly*, unless you are ordering by the Key**.

Related, you should read into [underlying caveats/limitations on cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Limitations_of_cursors) to get a better understanding:

> - Because the NOT_EQUAL and IN operators are implemented with multiple queries, queries that use them do not support cursors, nor do composite queries constructed with the CompositeFilterOperator.or method.
> - Cursors don't always work as expected with a query that uses an inequality filter or a sort order on a property with multiple values. The de-duplication logic for such multiple-valued properties does not persist between retrievals, possibly causing the same result to be returned more than once.

If the list of values used in `IN` is a static list rather than determined at runtime, a work around is to compute this as an indexed Boolean field when you write the Entity. This allows you to use a single equality filter. For example, if you have a bug tracker and you want to see a list of open issues, you might use a `IN('new', 'open', 'assigned')` restriction on your query. Alternatively, you could set a property called `is_open` to `True` instead, so you no longer need the `IN` condition.

---

* Computationally silly: Requires doing a linear scan over an unbounded number of preceding values to determine if the current retrieved Entity is a duplicate or not. Also known as conceptually not compatible with Cursors.

** Key works because we can alternate between different single queries  retrieving the next set of values and not have to worry about doing a linear scan over the entire proceeding result set. This gives us a bounded data set to work with.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around with the flag idea and see if I can get it to do what I want.